# How do you force a deploy to Heroku without doing a git commit

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I had a case where a push to heroku failed because of a database issue. I fixed it, but the only way I know to deploy is via "git push heroku master". Since I didn't commit anything, it won't push a new deployment. The only way I can get it to deploy to make some minor change and then do it. Is there  a way to force a deploy? I'm using play 2.1.2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are just trying to reload the dynos you can issue this from the command line:

heroku restart -a appname

More info https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/application-offline

Comment: I think this would work, I also needed a way to run the db evolution  script, which if a restart didn't go, I suppose I could do manually.

Comment: This doesn't work when 'Deployment failed' and `git push --force` is 'Everything up-to-date'.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a throw-away commit if you concern is to avoid actually saving the 'minor/dummy' commits to the repo permanently:

[Heroku Throwaway Commit](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/quietly-pushing-to-heroku/)

See Section: "Automating the throwaway commit"
The author has basically automated the above with a quick bash script; however, as the author indicates use with caution -- you wouldn't want to use this in other situations with un-tested code.

Comment: That may work, I think I actually just needed a way to restart, assuming the deployment was successful (still getting familiar with heroku, so I'm not sure if it was or not). Since the database issue caused the app startup to fail, once I fixed the database manually, I couldn't figure out how just restart it.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.darraghoriordan.com/2019/03/02/heroku-push-failed-force-rebuild/

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-releases-retry
heroku releases:retry
# or
heroku releases:retry --app darragh-starter
```

Comment: Doing this does not lead to a Stack Upgrade, if one is pending for the next deployment